# how to send cookies from client to server?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm using MEAN Stack. I made login/signup and profile page. I'm saving user id in cookies and now I want to send my id in server.

I'm getting my id from cookies like that:

```
userId = $cookies.get('userId')
```

How can i send this information to server ? I must find this information in DB with id like that:

```
var userId = "receivedId";
User.UserModel.findOne({ _id: userId }, function(err, data) {
    var User = {_id: data._id, user: data.user, date: data.date};
res.send(User); //I know how to send from server to client.
});
```

Comment: All web browsers automatically include all cookies for current domain to all http request, so your server is already receiving it.

Comment: but I wrote console.log(req.body); and result was undefined :/

Comment: Please, check your web server documentation. If you're using `express`, you'll have to configure [cookie-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser) middleware first. After that you'll be able to access client cookies using `req.cookies`.

Comment: this is my old project and maybe not working https://github.com/vatex/Address-Book :/

Comment: Thanks Leonid. I'll try this now! :*

Comment: New Ideas are Welcome!

Comment: Leonid I tried and it works ;)

Comment: Problem is solved friends!

Answer (score 0):

Please, check your web server documentation. If you're using express, you'll have to configure cookie-parser middleware first. After that you'll be able to access client cookies using req.cookies. – Leonid Beschastny

answers author is: Leonid Beschastny

thank you. it works!